# The Android studio does not recognize UnityLibrary

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

[image: projectDir]
[image: directory]

https://forum.unity.com/threads/integration-unity-as-a-library-in-native-android-app-version-2.751712/

I saw this article and copied it, but It couldn't recognize UnityLibrary.
What's the problem?

1. I added this code in settings.gradle file

   `include ':unityLibrary'`

`project(':unityLibrary').projectDir=new File('..\\unityLibrary')`

2. I added this code in build.gradle(Module: app) file

   `implementation project(':unityLibrary')`
   `implementation fileTree(dir:project(':unityLibrary').getProjectDir().toString() + ('\libs'), include: ['*.jar'])`
3. I added this code in build.gradle(Project: NativeAndroidApp) file

`flatDir { dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs" }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT9lw.png)
(It means it doesn't recognize it.)

Comment: What do you mean it couldn't recognize?

Comment: UnityLibrary does not open in Android studio. (I added a picture.)

Comment: Have you run gradle sync?

Comment: Yes, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @s1gap did you get the solution yet, I am also facing the same one with laTEST Android stuio ?

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem, there are several reasons that can occur and there are two scenarios you can face this problem.
first one :

if you are trying to build unity export directly, do not update the project with android studio. because when gradle is upgraded sometn occurs and it doest compile as it must be

seckond one:

if you are importing unity project to an android native project as a module or dependency, you should arrange your

```
*gradle.properties
*androidManifest.xml (ex. add your player activity)
*settings.gradle (ex. include ':unityLibrary')
```

and use the gradle version that you exported.  here is working examples:

settings.gradle:

```
include ':launcher', ':unityLibrary'
```

local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\amete\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
ndk.dir=C\:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.8f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
```

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.enableR8=false
unityStreamingAssets=.json, .dat, .xml
unityTemplateVersion=3
```

(project level)build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            // If you are changing the Android Gradle Plugin version, make sure it is compatible with the Gradle version preinstalled with Unity
            // See which Gradle version is preinstalled with Unity here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html
            // See official Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin compatibility table here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
            // To specify a custom Gradle version in Unity, go do "Preferences > External Tools", uncheck "Gradle Installed with Unity (recommended)" and specify a path to a custom Gradle version
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
            
        }
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs "${project(':unityLibrary').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```